# Suggested method to update value in object literal from promise callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I realize there are probably 10 ways to do this and I typically stumble through some clumsy way to achieve it - however I'd like to get a couple of ideas on "clean" ways to update a value in an object literal from a promise callback.

My current use case is:

```
let groups2 = {
    groupsList: [],
    updateGroups: () => {
        return axios({
            'url': 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/groups?per_page=500',
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'private-token': GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN,
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            groups2.groupsList = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

This works, however it "feels bad?" to reference "groups2" specifically from inside itself (in the callback in this case). Essentially I want a singleton that can operate on it's own values via functions that may contain promises. I'm looking for better ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you use an arrow function inside your object literal, it will not bind "this" to the object.  So in es2015 you can use the [shorthand syntax for method declarations on object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).  But you *will* want to use the arrow syntax inside the `.then` method---there it will bind "this" to the enclosing context:

```
let groups2 = {
    groupsList: [],
    updateGroups() {    // Change this
        return axios({
            'url': 'https://gitlab.com/api/v3/groups?per_page=500',
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'private-token': GITLAB_API_PRIVATE_TOKEN,
                'cache-control': 'no-cache'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => { // and this
            console.log(response);
            this.groupsList = response.data; // and use the "this" variable here
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, nice and clean - thank you! I don't think I fully grasped that there was a different between function syntax and the arrow syntax. I've just been treating them as interchangeable.